# Aurelia CLI - Import less file from node_modules to master less file

Tags: less, node-modules, aurelia

**Install package:**

```
npm install font-awesome --save
```

**Update aurelia.json:**

```
{
    "name": "font-awesome",
    "main":"",
    "path": "../node_modules/font-awesome",
    "resources": [
        "css/font-awesome.css",
        "/fonts/fontawesome-webfont.woff2",
        "/fonts/FontAwesome.otf",
        "/fonts/fontawesome-webfont.eot",
        "/fonts/fontawesome-webfont.svg",
        "/fonts/fontawesome-webfont.ttf"
    ]
}
```

**Import style in html page using require tag:**

```
<require from="font-awesome/css/font-awesome.css"></require>
```

No errors - Working as intended

**Import style using less and aurelia.config path (not working)**

```
@import (less) "font-awesome/css/font-awesome.css";
```

Error: not found - Doesn't find file when using import less in master less file.

**Import style using less and full node_modules path (working)**

```
@import (less) "node_modules/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.css";
```

No errors - Working as intended

1. Why doesn't import less find my file?
2. It's working fine when using full path to css file, but I read that you should avoid using full paths, correct? Why is that?
3. Perhaps I should include .less instead in my aurelia.json config?
4. If I use the full node_modules path and publish my projects, will I have any problems loading the library?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you updated the aurelia.json file, you are basically saying `"name": "font-awesome"` is in `"path": "../node_modules/font-awesome"`, so
`<require from="font-awesome/css/font-awesome.css"></require>` works because Aurelia knows where font-awesome is placed (like an alias).

But, with `@import (less) "font-awesome/css/font-awesome.css";` , you cant find the file because less doesn't know the alias.

`@import (less) "node_modules/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.css";` works because this is the real path where font-awesome is placed.

2. Actually, `node_modules/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.css` is relative to your current place, full path example is `/var/www/project/node_modules/..`, and this is bad because when you move your project to another place, this path could be wrong.
3. No need.
4. No problem with that, less will copy `font-awesome.css` contents inside this file (that's what *import* does).

Hope it helps.

Comment: Aha okey. Do you know anything about the other questions, 2, 3 and 4:)?